# MVC4 Formcollection not refreshing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model with a boolean property. The corresponding view looks like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TermsAccepted)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TermsAccepted)
```

In my controller, I do the following:

```
var validator = new MyModelValidator();
var model = new MyModel()
{            
    TermsAccepted = bool.Parse(form["TermsAccepted"])
};

var validationResult = validator.Validate(model);
    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
            warnings.Add(error.ErrorMessage);

return warnings;
```

The first time, I don't click on the checkbox, for the form value is 'false' and the validation message is shown. The second I do click on the checkbox, however the form value is now 'true,false' and an exception occurs.

Does the form have to be cleared somehow?

Comment: Why not just let the default model binder handle it? `FormCollection` is an easy way to cause problems and should generally be avoided...

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is because the Html.CheckBoxFor helper generates an additional hidden field with the same name as the checkbox and the value of false. When the checkbox is selected the 2 values are sent to the controller. The default model binder is perfectly capable of understanding and parsing this value. So if you used a view model instead of doing some horrible things with this FormCollection and manually parsing it, everything would have worked beautifully:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel model)
{
    var validator = new MyModelValidator();

    var validationResult = validator.Validate(model);
        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
            foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
                warnings.Add(error.ErrorMessage);


    ...

}
```

No need to use any FormCollection. Remove it from your code. Just pass the model as parameter to the action and the model binder will take care of the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot pass the model as parameter, because my class inherits from an other class and I need to use formcollection

Comment: No, you absolutely do not need to use FormCollection. You need to use a view model. Your controller action should always take a view model as parameter. The view model is a class that you specifically design to meet the requirements of a given view. FormCollection should never be used in a properly written ASP.NET MVC application. Parsing parameters back and forth from the request (as you currently do) instead of using what's built into the framework reminds me about the good old days of CGI :-)

Comment: I know what you mean but I have to adhere to the code I currently have and I have no other alternative apart from using formcollection.

Comment: Well then call the Regex wizards and split the `true,false` string before attempting to parse it to a boolean. OMG, it's incredible what kind of code people end up just because they don't use view models in their applications.